# Issue in Automatically Dismiss the AlertDialog Onclick Of Custom Button and Open Fragment instead of NegativeButton

Tags: java, android

Issue in Automatically Dismiss the AlertDialog Onclick Of Custom Button and Open Fragment instead of  NegativeButton.

```
//AlertDialog 
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

    //Creating a redirectItem Button on AlertDialog 
     final Button redirectItem = new Button(getContext());
                    redirectItem.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getCurrActivity(), R.color.lightPink));
                    redirectItem.setText("Add Item");
                    redirectItem.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getCurrActivity(), R.color.white));
                    redirectItem.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

//Attach Listner to the redirectItem Button Onclick of Button Fragment Should be Open 
    redirectItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                            Fragment fragment = new Fragment1();
                            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.frag_container, fragment).commit();

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: builder never dismisses you have to make alert dialog  and then dismiss it

Comment: I Already Created Alerdialog .                                                                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                alert.setTitle("Add Item");                                                       final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.show();

Comment: Oh ok i didnt see that it was not specified in the code

Comment: What exactly you wanted to do???

Comment: Try to do something like this by creating a customized class for onclick listener     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836183/dismiss-alertdialog-builder-from-onclick

Comment: I want automatically dismiss the alertdialog onclick of custom Button instead   of AlertPositive or AlertNegative or Backpressed Button.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
            alert.show();

            // do something

            alert.dismiss();
```